# Problema con suma de filas en pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Por favor me pueden ayudar a resolver este problema:

Estoy intentando **sumar de dos filas en mi dataframe y guadar el resultado en una nueva columna** pero no ha funcionado con el codigo con el que lo intento resolver.

**Estos son los datos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea seria ir sumando los dos primeros datos(filas 0 y 1) de la colunma **Saldo_total** y guadarlos en una nueva columna con los resultados, luego sumar los dos datos que siguen(filas 2 y 3) y guardar el resultado en la nueva columna y asi sucesivamente ir sumando de dos en dos.

hasta el momento he estado intentando con varios codigos no obteniendo el resultado:

dftotales['variacion']=dftotales.iloc[:,[0,1]].sum(axis = 0)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**De antemano muchas gracias**

Comment: Buen día, ¿En la nueva columna, el resultado de la suma debe ir en las dos filas involucradas? Por favor edita tu pregunta, agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto, no como imagen para que podamos reutilizar la información y agrega un ejemplo del resultado deseado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que un método relativamente simple puede ser el utilizar una "ventana rodante" (*rolling window*) de tamaño 2 y aplicar `.sum()` sobre el resultado de esa ventana.

Para ilustrarlo voy a usar datos con valores numéricos más pequeños, porque si no no se ve nada (además de que números tan grandes serían convertidos a float por pandas, con lo que se ve todavía menos). Partamos del siguiente dataframe de entrada:

```
    año  Saldo_total
O  2020            3
1  2021            3
2  2020            2
3  2021            6
4  2020            1
5  2021            8
```

Mi idea es aplicar `df.Saldo_total.rolling(2).sum()`. Esto va recorriendo la columna `Saldo_total` agrupando cada dato con el anterior y sumándolos. Así en la fila 0 el resultado será NaN porque no hay dato anterior. En la fila 1 el resultado será 6 (valor actual = 3 más valor anterior = 3). En la fila 2 el valor será 2+3=5, en la fila 3 será 6+2=8, etc. Los resultados salen por tanto:

```
O    NaN
1    6.0
2    5.0
3    8.0
4    7.0
5    9.0
```

Esto es casi lo que buscabas salvo que habría que "desplazar hacia arriba" los resultados para quitar el Nan de la fila 0 y cambiarlo por 6.0 etc. Eso se logra con `.shift(-1)`. Por tanto:

```
>>> df.Saldo_total.rolling(2).sum().shift(-1)
O    6.0
1    5.0
2    8.0
3    7.0
4    9.0
5    NaN
```

> **Nota** Como señala HeytalePazguato en un comentario, el mismo resultado puede obtenerse de forma más breve en este caso, así:
>
> ```
> df.Saldo_total + df.Saldo_total.shift(-1)
> ```

De cualquiera de las dos formas, los resultados que buscas están en los índices pares (0, 2, 4..) los de los índices impares en principio no te interesan. No queda claro en tu pregunta cómo rellenar el valor de los índices impares. Quizás quieras repetir el mismo valor que aparece en los índices pares, quizás quieras rellenarlos con NaN.

Rellenarlos con NaN es fácil. Basta asignar `np.nan` a los índices cuyo módulo 2 salga distinto de cero. Ya de paso guardamos el resultado en una nueva columna del dataframe como tú pedías:

```
df["suma2"] = df.Saldo_total.rolling(2).sum().shift(-1)
df.loc[resultado.index % 2!=0, "suma2"] = np.nan
```

El nuevo dataframe queda así:

```
    año  Saldo_total  suma2
0  2020            3    6.0
1  2021            3    NaN
2  2020            2    8.0
3  2021            6    NaN
4  2020            1    9.0
5  2021            8    NaN
```

Finalmente, si no quieres esos `NaN` puedes usar `.fillna()` para cambiarlos por otra cosa (por ejemplo por una cadena vacía o un guión), o si quieres que se repita el valor de las filas pares puedes usar `.fillna(method="ffill")`:

```
df = df.fillna(method="ffill")
print(df)
```

```
    año  Saldo_total  suma2
0  2020            3    6.0
1  2021            3    6.0
2  2020            2    8.0
3  2021            6    8.0
4  2020            1    9.0
5  2021            8    9.0
```

Comment: Segun yo, puedes hacerlo también con `df['suma'] = df['Saldo_total'] + df['Saldo_total'].shift(-1)` en lugar de `rolling` para no tener que utilizar 2 funciones.

Comment: Pues sí, es buena idea para este caso en que solo se quieren sumar dos valores. ¿Por qué no lo añades como respuesta?

Comment: Si lo pensé pero todo lo demás es igual al proceso que muestras con los nan o repetir el valor de las filas, por eso pensé que un comentario sería mejor para que no hubiera dos respuestas casi iguales

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Ok, pues he añadido tu comentario a mi respuesta para mayor visibilidad. Gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus aportes, funciono 100%